# Excel: Individual labels for data points in a group

Tags: excel, charts

I'm plotting a scatter plot with three columns:

Green group:

```
x       y       pointlabel

48,6    -0,45%  12
31,2    -6,64%  51
34,3    -1,58%  31
33,6    -10,97% 63
64,6    3,42%   55
45,4    5,89%   35
35,7    -3,11%  23
36,2    -1,24%  21
11,2    -1,18%  15
70      -6,35%  67
62,4    -10,10% 12
```

Red group:

..

Yellow group:

..

Now I want to plot a scatter plot with each number above like this:

[image]

But trying I get this:

[image]

Is it possible to make a single label for each point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no native Excel way to do this automatically.

However, this free add-in will do what you want:

> **Add XY Chart Labels** - Adds labels to the points on your XY Chart data
>   series based on any range of cells in the workbook.

http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/ChartLabeler.htm

Comment: Thanks I'll give your solution a try